# SuiteScript 2.0 - Load Custom Record Table Data

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Within Customization -> List, Records & Fields -> Custom Records I have a table with id: customrecord_{name} with the type "customrecordtype". I have multiple fields in that record

[image]

How can I use the load function to get all the data for this table/record? (For all the fields)

```
const data= record.load({
                type: 'customrecord_{name}',
                isDynamic: false
                ... //get all fields
});
```

I tried to look at the help center but am a bit lost on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `load` won't do it. After loading a custom record with `load`, you can check all the fields of this custom record by calling `data.getFields()` method. This will return a list of field ids (including custom ones) that you can fetch by calling `data.getValue` such as `data.getValue({'fieldId':'isinactive'}) // a regular field` or `data.getValue({'fieldId':'custrecord_routeproduce_highpriority'}) // a custom field`

[loading a custom record, checking its fields, fetching value of a custom field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjdY3.png)